# Python BaseHTTPRequestHandler server works for first GET request only

Tags: python, http, webserver

I'm working on trying create a super basic python webserver based on BaseHTTPRequestHandler. When I perform the GET request to the address 127.0.0.1/a for the first time, everything works well and I recover an image on my browser.

However, when I repeat this GET request a second time, I do not get anything. Tracing the code, I can see that the code itself is running through the entire do_GET(self) segment.

I'm really confused as to why the webserver would work the first time and not the next.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer  
from os import curdir, sep


imagefile = "a.jpg"
imagepage =open(curdir+sep+imagefile, 'rb')

notfound = "File not found"

class webserverHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')                
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With") 

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/a":
            print("getting thg jpg file")
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type","image/png")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(imagepage.read())
    else:
        self.send_error(404, notfound) 

def main():
    try:
        port = 1234
        server = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', port), webserverHandler)
        print("Web server is running on port {}".format(port))
        server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("^C entered, stopping web server...")

    finally:
        if server:
            print("closing server")
            server.socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
def do_GET(self):
    notfound = "File not found"
    if self.path == "/a":
        print("getting thg jpg file")
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type","image/png")
        self.end_headers()
        imagefile = "fig1.png"
        imagepage =open(curdir+sep+imagefile, 'rb')
        self.wfile.write(imagepage.read())
    else:
        self.send_error(404, notfound)
```

Please read file in each request.

**Why:**
`imagepage.read()` make file seek to end of the image file, So, we cannot read any data with next `imagepage.read()` from second request.

---

Or
We can use `imageContent = imagepage.read()` at first,
and we can send `imageContent` every request
    from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
    from os import curdir, sep

```
imagefile = "fig1.png"
imagepage =open(curdir+sep+imagefile, 'rb')
imageContent = imagepage.read() # Read Image here

notfound = "File not found"

class webserverHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')                
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With") 

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/a":
            print("getting thg jpg file")
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type","image/png")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(imageContent)
        else:
            self.send_error(404, notfound) 

def main():
    try:
        port = 1234
        server = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', port), webserverHandler)
        print("Web server is running on port {}".format(port))
        server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("^C entered, stopping web server...")

    finally:
        if server:
            print("closing server")
            server.socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ohhhh! I understand what I was doing wrongly now. Thank you so much for your help!